# How can i add a Select Option in AMP

Tags: drupal, amp-html

I have a page with a Select Option

[image]

but in my AMP Page i cant see this element,

What i need to add to this work?

Answer (score 1):

For navigate the page use `AMP.navigateTo`

```
 <select on="change:AMP.navigateTo(url=event.value)">
    <option selected>-Select a Page-</option>
    <option value="YOUR-PAGE-URL">Home Page</option>  
    <option value="YOUR-PAGE-URL">About Us</option>
    <option value="YOUR-PAGE-URL">Camping Tips</option>
  </select>
```